# Wait on InvokePattern.Invoke()

Tags: c#, wpf, automation

I'm trying to automate some UI testing. I have a window that calculates something based on some textboxes once you click a button. I've got the button correctly being clicked, but I can't correctly get the result of the claculation because the calculate() method is being called after I check for the correct answer in the test.

```
InvokePattern pattern = element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
pattern.Invoke();
```

Calling Invoke() doesn't block, so it immediately returns and then starts checking if `calculate()` worked even though it hasn't been called yet. How can I change the Invoke() call so that it waits until after calculate() has been called?

element is the `AutomationElement` for my button.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double v1 = 0;
            double v2 = 0;

            if(Double.TryParse(tbVal1.Text, out v1) && Double.TryParse(tbVal2.Text, out v2))
            {
                double output = v1 + v2;
                tbAnswer.Text = "The answer is " + output.ToString();
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
I ended up taking a different route to my solution by subscribing the the InvokePattern.InvokedEvent event. This allowed me to put whatever logic I needed into the event handler to react to the invoking of the AutomationElement.

```
InvokePattern pattern = element.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;

 Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, element, TreeScope.Element,
               new AutomationEventHandler(OnUIAutomationEvent));
  pattern.Invoke();
```

Let me know if I need to add anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you calling Invoke?  Are you calling it in another thread, because from your description it sounds like you are calling it in the UI thread which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I have the calculate code inside the handler just for simplicity. I could call the calculate method directly, but I'd also like to see the affects on the UI from automating the button click. I don't think calling Invoke from the UI thread is the issue since invoke returns immediately, and there's nothing blocking in what its calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [these guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753352.aspx), the InvokedEvent should be raised by the control:

> InvokedEvent is raised on a control that has been activated (as a response to a control carrying out its associated action). If possible, the event should be raised after the control has completed the action and returned without blocking. The Invoked event should be raised before servicing the Invoke request in the following scenarios:
>
> It is not possible or practical to wait until the action is complete.
>
> The action requires user interaction.
>
> The action is time-consuming and will cause the calling client to block for a significant amount of time.

Comment: I read that article, but it seemed more like it was for implementing the InvokePattern for UserContols and such. What do you mean by the InvokedEvent should be raised on the control itself?

Comment: @wangburger, That is not how I read it. The quote in my answer is directly from the article. I did not write that. the way I understand it is that after the the click has been handled/executed by the control this event should be raised. If the control does this, the automation client is able to subscribe to this event and will be called when all processing has been done.

Comment: Subscribing to that event is the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to subscribe to it. Thanks for your help pointing me to that.